# Sharepoint 2016 create library from Explorer view

Tags: document-library, open-with-explorer, explorer-view

I have received an inquiry from user about the way to create library.

Situation

1. The user(who has Full Control permission) opened the library by "Open with Explorer".
2. He copied and pasted that library in Explorer view.
3. New folder is created but it is not shown in "Site Contents" view in Sharepoint Site.
4. He said that it it wired because it was shown in the other day.

I am confused with this situation because in my understand, the folder won't shown when it was created in Explorer view.

But, he insists that there must be the way to show that folder and tell him the way.

Is there any solution to display the folder which was copied in Explorer view, in "Site Content" view?

I am truly appreciate for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a Document Library from the Explorer view. You can create Folders, but that doesn't translate into a Doc Lib; rather it translates into a Folder object. This object will not appear in the Site Contents view, but you should be able to see it via Explorer or SharePoint Designer.

Comment: Dear Trevor, 
Thanks so much for your quick answer.
I will tell it to user and reconfirm his operation again.